# Unity - Unexpected Symbol ";" in class, struct or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

having a slight problem. I am reworking a project of mine using SpriteFactory, and have used a youtube following the exact same code as his but running into the following error:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using SpriteFactory;
public class Running : MonoBehaviour {

private SpriteFactory.Sprite;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    sprite = GetComponent<Sprite> ();
    }

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
        Sprite.Play("Run");
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        pos.x += Time.deltaTime * 2;
        transform.position = pos;
        }
    else{
        sprite.Stop();
}
}
}
```

Error It results in is Unexpected Symbol ";" in class, struct or interface member declaration which i know is referring to:

`private SpriteFactory.Sprite;`

but I am not even sure why? Suggestions

Comment: You need a varaiable name after `SpriteFactory.Sprite`

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply. I have added a variable now but its coming up with 'Sprite is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Sprite' and 'SpriteFactory.Sprite'.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go :)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
// below solved conflict of class names
// we won't "using" whole SpriteFactory namespace because
// both UnityEngine and SpriteFactory have got same class "Sprite"
// so we pull out only needed class
using FactorySprite = SpriteFactory.Sprite;
public class Running : MonoBehaviour {

   // you forgot to set name of variable representing your sprite
   private FactorySprite sprite;

   // Use this for initialization
   void Start () {
      sprite = GetComponent<FactorySprite> (); // Edited
   }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {
     if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
        sprite.Play("Run"); // heh, remember C# is case sensitive :)
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        pos.x += Time.deltaTime * 2;
        transform.position = pos;
     }
     else{
        sprite.Stop();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this is now followed by another error:

"Sprite is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Sprite' and 'SpriteFactory.Sprite'.

Comment: I edited code, try now and tell us if doesn't work ;)

Comment: Hi,

Many thanks for your your help, however, has followed up with another error on (11,26) which follows:

Type 'UnityEngine.Sprite' must be convertible to 'UnityEngine.Component' in order to use it as a parameter 'T' in the generic type of method 'UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent<T>()'

Comment: Hi,

Think its just one final error now, saying 'UnityEngine.Sprite' does not contain a definition for 'Play'

Comment: As you can tell im a complete notice. Many Thanks for your help =)